Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer
I have a Samsung Galaxy A3 (SM-A320FL). My phone showed "Google Play services has stopped" all the time and I could not fix it, so I decided to wipe my phone and start new.
When I'm in the interface of the "Team Win Recovery Project" and click "Wipe", > Advanced wipe, select Data and click "Repair file system", I get the following error message:
Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer. 
Failed to mount '/data' (invalid argument) 
Unable to recreate /data/media folder. 


Up to this point, I have tried a lot but nothing could fix my issue. I also used the "wipe" Change File System for Data trick, where you change the file system to EXT2 and then back to EXT4, I still get the same error.
I can't find a reliable Android version for my old phone on the https://developers.google.com page.
At this point, my phone won't start anymore but only shows the "Samsung logo". I can only get in the Download or Boot mode but can not start my phone anymore.

Google does not provide Android ROMs for Samsung devices. ROMs are always provided by the device manufacturer. You should better download the latest stock ROM for your device and install it. Samsung images can e.g. obtained using samloader project.

you have installed TWRP that's why you can't boot. format data and disable dm-verity, then it will boot. if you want TWRP access on /data disable encryption
